# Prove $T$ is normal if $\| T^*v \| \le \| Tv \|$ for every $v$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Suppose $T \in L(V)$ and $\| T^*v \| \le \| Tv 
> \|$ for every $v \in V$. Prove that $T$ is normal.

This is a problem from section 7A of the book *Linear algebra done right 4th edition*. Here is what I have proceeded so far:
Suppose $ e_1 e_2 ... e_n$ is an orthonormal basis of V. Using Riesz Representation theorem on the equation $\langle Tv, w \rangle = \langle v, T^*w \rangle$, I get $$ T^*w= \sum_i^n{\langle w, Te_i \rangle e_i}$$ From the condition in the problem I have $$ \langle (TT^* - T^*T)v, v \rangle \leq 0 $$
Now substitute the formula for $T^*$ above, I got
$$ \begin{equation}\sum_i^n{\lvert\langle v, Te_i \rangle\rvert^2} - \sum_i^n{\langle Tv, Te_i \rangle\langle e_i, v \rangle} \leq 0 \end{equation}$$
The question is how can I proceed further to prove the above inequality is an equality and hence $TT^* - T^*T = 0 $ to conclude that $T$ is normal?

Comment: Hint: $TT^\ast-T^\ast T$ is negative semidefinite and it has a zero trace.

Comment: @user1551 trace and definiteness is introduced in later chapters of the book. Can I solve the problem without using these?

Comment: Another hint: let $u$ be a unit eigenvector of $T$. Show that $\|T^\ast u\|\ge|\langle u,T^\ast u\rangle|\ge\|Tu\|$. When does Cauchy-Schwarz inequality become an equality?

Comment: @user1551 With $u$ a unit eigenvector of $T$.,∥T∗u∥≥|⟨u,T∗u⟩|≥∥Tu∥ is an equality. I know the first $\ge$ comes from the C-S inequality but why is the second $\ge$ , I can only get $\lvert\langle u, T^*u\rangle\rvert = \lvert\langle Tu, u\rangle\rvert \le \lvert\lvert Tu \rvert\rvert$. And I don't understand why can we assume an eigenvector of T exists since the problem doesn't assume a complex vector space

Comment: It doesn’t matter if it is a real vector space or not. By picking an orthonormal basis for the inner product space, the given condition can be converted into one in terms of matrices and you may assume that $T$ is a real square matrix and the inner product in question is the standard one for $\mathbb R^n$. Now, if $\|T^\ast v\|_2\le\|Tv\|_2$ for all real vectors $v$, the inequality also holds for all complex vectors $v$, because $\|T(x+iy)\|_2^2=\|Tx\|_2^2+\|Ty\|_2^2$ for real vectors $x$ and $y$, and likewise for $\|T^\ast(x+iy)\|_2$. Hence we may consider the problem over $\mathbb C$.

Comment: OK, a third hint: for any orthonormal basis $\{u_1,u_2,\ldots,u_n\}$ of $V$, we have
$$
\operatorname{tr}(TT^\ast)
=\sum_i\|T^\ast u_i\|^2
\le\sum_i\|Tu_i\|^2
=\operatorname{tr}(T^\ast T)
=\operatorname{tr}(TT^\ast).
$$

Comment: @user1551 Sorry, I'm too dumb to understand this. Does it mean for any orthonormal basis of $V$ , $\sum_i{\lvert\lvert T*u_i \rvert\rvert}^2 = \sum_i{\lvert\lvert Tu_i \rvert\rvert}^2$ always holds. Then I guess I need to generalize the equality to any $v = \sum_i{a_iu_i}$. But I completely lost in the computation as I substitute $v$ as a linear combination of $u_i$s into that equation...

Comment: (1) Yes, it is true. One of the sums is equal to $\operatorname{tr}(TT^\ast)$ while the other is equal to $\operatorname{tr}(T^\ast T)$. So, by the tracial property $\operatorname{tr}(AB)=\operatorname{tr}(BA)$, the two traces — and hence the two sums — are equal. This holds for any (normal or non-normal) linear operator $T$ in a finite-dimensional inner product space. (2) There is no need to deal with the coordinates of $v$. Just take $u_1=v/\|v\|$ and extend $u_1$ to an orthonormal basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that $\langle v,(TT^*-T^*T)v\rangle\leq0$. Since $TT^*-T^*T$ is self-adjoint, all eigenvalues of it is real. Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of it and $v$ be the corresponding eigenvector, then $\lambda \langle v,v\rangle=\langle v,(TT^*-T^*T)v\rangle\leq0\Rightarrow \lambda\leq0$. But $tr(TT^*-T^*T)=0$. So all eigenvalues of $TT^*-T^*T$ is $0$. Hence $TT^*-T^*T=0$, as $TT^*-T^*T$ is self adjoint.